# Profile avatar lost on several sites after profile edit (Gravatar replaced with Identicon)

Tags: bug, profile-picture, gravatar

I have had the same network-wide profile avatar for many years; it's a custom image which I installed nework-wide soon after I registered for Stack Overflow back in 2011. I still see that image e.g. on [my Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) and [my network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/468289/tripleee) but not, for instance, on this site, or e.g. on [Super User](https://superuser.com/users/97118/tripleee)

(The example originally linked to my Unix & Linux profile instead of Super User but I experimentally changed my profile back to the gravatar one there.)

I routinely update my profile presentation text every few months, and did so again a few days ago. Comments below seem to indicate that others who recently edited their profile are experiencing the same problem.

My preferred avatar is a Gravatar which is connected to my email address, which has always been the same (MD5 091f411d57db5be8298e057a32e5ad72). The replacement seems to be a generic identicon with a different MD5. I don't recall seeing this identicon as an option in my profile before:

[image: Profile editor shows Gravatar and Identicon (selected)]

You'll notice that the gravatar is still visible as an option, but I can find no way to replace it on all sites in one go. I switched back to the gravatar one on Unix & Linux and noticed that the help next to the "Save" button says

> Your profile will be updated on all public communities.

but alas, that did not in fact happen. Do I really have to go over 170+ member sites and manually select my gravatar on each?

Comment: Well, no. There's no such avatar change for my profile. _"I routinely update my profile presentation text every few months, and did so again a few days ago)?"_ I don't do that though. I know what your avatar should look like.

Comment: Where is your image hosted?

Comment: Don't use gravatar ...

Comment: It seems like your Gravatar hash got changed from `091f411d57db5be8298e057a32e5ad72` to `73986d6800efc2a6dd8e1a323ee179a5` somehow. I don't know how this could have happened.

Comment: I’m not sure if this is the [same issue I had years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283643/323179), but either way, gravitar is not a trustworthy image hosting service.

Comment: @Laurel Consider that in 2011, the *only* way to have an avatar was through Gravatar.

Comment: I suspect your [legacy email field](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341930/140890) either got cleared or a software update is rolling out switching gravatar to the verified email field instead.

Comment: I can confirm that the legacy email field on Stack Overflow for your account matches the MD5 hash for your old gravatar. Moderators can’t see your verified email address as far as I know so I can’t verify where the other hash comes from. Check yours at https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current and use [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=MD5()) to verify if that’s the source for the new hash.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So is there any recourse, or do I need to go over my profile on 170+ sites and update the avatar on each if it's wrong? I vaguely recall seeing an "apply this profile on all sites" kind of button when doing profile edits but I can't seem to find it now.

Comment: @tripleee I don’t know. I don’t even know if your new gravatar is based on your verified email. A verified email address is tied to your network account so would only need to be updated once, by the way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I definitely have Gravatar baed on my verified email address (MD5 091f411d57db5be8298e057a32e5ad72) since back when I first created that Gravatar profile picture. I guess with "new" you mean "relative to when I first signed up"?

Comment: That's not the MD5 of your 'wrong' gravatar, so it is *not* based on your verified email address.

Comment: Area51 doesn't seem to think this email is actually "verified" because it offers to send a new verification email...? Curious to see it still has very old profile information.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The /email/settings/current email is the same one as everywhere else; where should I look for the verified email if not there? Or are you saying it's there but it's not verified? (How would that change the MD5 though?)

Comment: Area51 is old software and doesn't use the newer verified email setting. It is the only place that still exposes the old per-site-account email address, the one that your Stack Overflow gravatar is still based on.

Comment: As for me asking you to check the verified email address: I was merely trying to troubleshoot here, to find the source of the new gravatar hash. I don't know where it comes from and had a hypothesis, one that proved wrong.

Comment: On Unix&Linux in the "Edit profile" tab, the "Change picture" dropdown on the profile picture shows "Identicon" (new fugly icon; selected), "Gravatar" (my familiar custom image), and "Upload a new picture". Perhaps the third option here is what I really want? What would cause the preference to change to Identicon on some, but not all sites, anyway?

Comment: I experimentallty changed to Gravatar on my U&L profile. The text next to the "Save" button says this will change my profile across the network, but I still see the Identicon on Ask Ubuntu, Webmasters, etc.

Comment: More information on how the email system works and what the legacy and verified fields mean: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341932/a-users-original-email-address-is-retained-in-the-system-even-after-theyve-cha (read it all)

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343537/377214 regarding Area 51 verification.

Comment: But it's the same email address everywhere, I have been vaguely miffed that an address I originally created for SO had to be used on another 170+ sites too but it's the same email everywhere and I have never changed it.

Comment: It looks to me like the new MD5 is derived from something else than my email address. My current mental model is that something somewhere connects my account to a basically random MD5 for the purpose of displaying an identicon.

Comment: The system uses a salt when calculating the Gravatar hash of users who haven't registered for Gravatar, to avoid leaking email addresses accidentally. (Those who've registered for it are deemed to be aware of it and choosing to waive this protection.) I think what happened is that something weird happened on some end, which resulted in the system thinking you're not registered for Gravatar and thus adding the salt when it's not supposed to, leading to the change.

Comment: I ran today in the same issue, however that legacy mail field cannot be the reason, I didn't change my mail address over the time

Comment: @rekire Neither did I -- I have had the same, single email address since I first registered.

Comment: It happened right after I edited my profile and applied it to all sites. Likely that this was the trigger. Might be something like identicon vs. gravatar. No idea why this value has changed here on meta

Comment: I have the exact same problem, and it also seems to have happened right after I made a change to one profile (at CrossValidated) and propagated it across all sites. This looks like a bona fide bug.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks for chiming in. Do you see your original profile picture on Cross Validated, and the wrong one on (most but not all) other sites?

Comment: @rekire And you, do you remember on which site you edited and if so do you see the correct picture on that particular site?

Comment: @tripleee: I see my original picture on CV and Meta.CV. I see one Gravatar on SO and Meta.SO, and a different one on Meta, Academia, Meta.Academia, History, Meta.History and Philosophy.

Comment: Hmmm, I see the same one https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbb6d365a52df4e3b602f01dfff26fb8?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1 for you on both Stack Overflow and Academia.

Comment: This is bug in Gravatar. Sadly enough, nobody there cares so SE is helpless. Why they keep suggesting people to use something so bad and broken is beyond me. :/

Comment: @tripleee it was stack overflow, there the picture didn't change

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou I don't think so, there is a bug in updating the profile for all sites in the network

Comment: I suspect this is related to an identical issue I had a few weeks ago: [My gravatar stopped working on most of stack exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344937/my-gravatar-stopped-working-on-most-of-stack-exchange)

Comment: and also in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41278/282094): "If you are changing using Gravatar, it will be updated in all sites where your **e-mail address is the same** as Gravatar.".

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate of the older question, though I agree that @Gavin's question seems identical. Still no idea how to change back the icon on all sites which suddenly switched to the generic identicon, or why this happened.

Comment: The *fix* (or workaround) is to do as [Tensibai commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344937/my-gravatar-stopped-working-on-most-of-stack-exchange#comment1155951_344937) and upload your avatar to Stack Exchange, copying it to all sites; you can then modify individual sites (and their child meta) to each be different from the other if you wish. A half dozen of my sites have *theme-based* avatars where I'm depicted doing something appropriate for the site's subject. --- As other comments have mentioned: Using outside equipment leads to multiple places to file your bug but not here.

Comment: @Rob I actually tried that but nothing happened. I vaguely speculate that the code somehow identified the uploaded image as identical to an existing image. Hmmm, I'll try with some random cat picture I guess.

Comment: I temporarily switched to a random cat and then uploaded my main avatar picture again. Seems to be okay now, thanks! (Except the fugly cat is still lingering in chat.)

Comment: Tripleee, OK. I was going to reply this: I'm guessing that [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WmjC.jpg), provides you with **no** ***new*** **information**. - But glad it's 'fixed' (worked around, but not actually repaired).

Comment: Somebody who is still on gravatar might try to see if they can repro the "I can't replace the gravatar image with an identical uploaded image" corner case, or it was just a fluke when I tried.

Comment: Tripleee, your uploaded image is 80x80 (tiny), why not use your GitHub one: https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/2160915

Comment: @Rob Thanks, I don't see much difference but I guess some people do.

Comment: I just had the same issue today. I did indeed go through all my networks and change back from identicon to gravatar, only to find all my respective meta site profiles are still using identicon. Here's the weird part: **The only way to force my meta profiles to change from identicon to gravatar is to click "Ask a question".** As soon as the page for asking a question loads, my icon reverts to gravatar for the meta site. This isn't a client-side issue, viewing my profile in incognito displays identicon too. I've been able to reproduce this behavior on every single network I have an account on.

Comment: Still happening a month and a half later.

Comment: @Kevin it seems that Stack Overflow is prioritization nowerdays by the business impact, since they don't loose money they don't care anymore. :-(

Comment: This recently happened to me (or I recently just noticed it), maybe after attempting to use a hat across all SE sites?

Answer (score 7):

I've been seeing this issue starting around the time of the question. It may be a hosting issue as [@Laurel posited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345627/profile-avatar-lost-on-several-sites-after-profile-edit-gravatar-replaced-with/346535#comment1157959_345627). Choosing my old custom avatar on one site and `Save and copy changes to all public communities` did not copy anything. Only the one site was updated. It did work after **uploading a new image from scratch**.

1. [image: Edit profile and settings]
2. [image: Change picture]
3. [image: Upload a new picture]   <=== especially this
4. [image: Drag and drop]
5. [image: Add picture]
6. [image: Save and copy changes to all public communities] <=== and this

Comment: Just for the record, was the uploaded image identical to your gravatar image?

Comment: @tripleee no it was different. That would be freaky if that made a difference wouldn't it?

Comment: It would indeed, and yet I would not rule that out.