# Network Linked Profiles reverting to Identicons

Tags: bug, user-accounts, profile-picture, gravatar, identicon

Yesterday when i went onto Movies and TV i noticed that rather than my Gravatar avatar appearing i had an Identicon. this is also the case on Arqade, Scifi and Stack Overflow so i assume on all other accounts i have linked. thing is Anime and Manga is unaffected.

On Movies and TV i sent to set the avatar to Gravatar but the chnage did to apply to all my accounts, Arqade, Scifi and Stack Overflow remaining the same. i also changed the "About me" section on Anime and Manga while i had Gravatar set, the About Me changes on all the sites but the avatar doesn't and i know i am pressing "Save Profile" and not the "customize your profile just on this community." link. and my [Stack Exchange Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1017597/memor-x?tab=accounts) shows the correct avatar (though chnages have to be imported into it)

Now i went onto Movies and TV today and found it's been changed back to my Identicon. and i know i changed it to Gravatar because [Chat cached it on the transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54360646#54360646)

[image: cached chat posts]

now yesterday it would have just been an inconvenience to go through all my accounts to fix this (was going to just focus on sites i frequent for now) but now it's more than that if Movies and TV reset, and i just don't understand why Anime and Manga is unaffected (it is set as my parent user in Chat so maybe that explains it)

I would probably upload my avatar to SE's imgur but given how changing the avatar from Identicon to Gravatar didn't propagate though all my accounts, i don't want to individually upload to every account.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: This is quite likely either the same as, or at least closely related to, the issue in [Profile picture using Identicon on most sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347874/562482) asked just an hour earlier.

Comment: @JohnOmielan i suspect the same issue and that i've noticed it will reset even if you change it. i did search a few hours ago, should have done a re-search before i posted