# I no longer have a profile photo outside of Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, profile-page, profile-picture

On Stack Overflow I have a [profile photo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/161801/asmeurer?tab=profile), but on all other Stack Exchange sites, my photo has been replaced with an automatically generated avatar.

I tried going to https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/161801 and clicking "save and copy changes to all public communities", but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I have no idea when this happened as I don't visit this site very often and it's not something I would necessarily notice, but I am pretty sure it didn't always used to be this way.

Comment: It looks like you're using Gravatar. This has been reported before, there's a solution in the answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345627/profile-avatar-lost-on-several-sites-after-profile-edit-gravatar-replaced-with). Good luck!

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I would prefer to keep my avatar as a gravatar. I don't want to update StackOverflow separately every time I update my gravatar.

Comment: Hmm. It's still the same bug though, so I think this is still a duplicate. I'm sorry to hear the workaround won't work for you...  I can't force the avatar for you either. Let me know if there's anything I'm missing though!